# UILocalNotification Special Characters Alert Body

Tags: ios, ios5, uilocalnotification, ios4

When generating a UILocalNotification on iOS 5.1.1 I am unable to show special characters such as '%' in the alertBody.  Apple's documentation specifically states that the string formatter for '%' char is '%%'.

Here is the relevant code:

```
UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:20.0];

localNotification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Test %%"];
NSLog(@"Local notification's alert body is %@",localNotification.alertBody);
localNotification.alertAction = @"View";

localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

The same thing happens if I try to specify the alertBody absolutely:
     localNotification.alertBody = @"Test %";

I have tried the same code to generate a UIAlertView which works perfectly.  Is this an iOS bug?

Answer (score 0):

I found a partial solution which involves using

```
localNotification.alertBody = @"%%%%";
```

to generate one '%' character.  I am guessing that this is a double processing bug in iOS.

Answer (score -1):

I know it says that the formatter is %% but normally in strings you use the backslash \ as an escape. So try: "Test \%" instead.

Comment: localNotification.alertBody = @"Test \%";  Behaves exactly the same as above :(  The "Test" part is printed but the '%' char is missing.

Comment: It came up as "The same thing happens if I try to specify the alertBody absolutely: localNotification.alertBody = @"Test %";" in your post, the backspace decided to go AWOL, I assumed that what you wrote was correct.